# Using Ajax to create session and echo results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying my best to get this to work. But AJAX is pretty new to me. So hang in there...

Ok, I've asked a couple of questions here about getting this issue that I'm having to work. I (We)'ve come a long way. But now the next issue is here.

I'm trying to *echo a session* in a div using **AJAX**.
The AJAX code is working, I can echo plain text to the div I want it to go. *The only problem I have is it does not display the title of the item.*

I have some items (lets say 3 for this example) and I would like to have the custom save the Items in a Session. So when the customer clicks on save. The ajax div displays the title. And if the custom clicks the 3rd item it show the 1st and 3rd item, etc...

**My HTML:**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-attribute="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-whatever="<?php the_title(); ?>">Sla deze boot op <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
```

**My AJAX code:**

```
$(".ajaxform").submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "example.com/reload.php",
      success: function(data) {
        $(".txtHint").html(data);    
       },
     error: function() {
        alert('Not OKay');
        }
    });
      return false;
 });
```

My PHP **reload.php**:

```
<h4>Saved Items</h4>
<p>Blaat...</p>
<?php echo "Product Name = ". $_SESSION['item'];?>
```

I saw this code on here: *I'm not using this code. Only wondering if I can use it for my code, and then how?*

Change session.php to this:

```
<?php
   session_start();

   // store session data
   $_SESSION['productName'] = $_POST['productName'];

   //retrieve session data
   echo "Product Name = ". $_SESSION['productName'];
?>
```

And in your HTML code:

```
function addCart(){
    var brandName = $('iframe').contents().find('.section01a h2').text();

    $.post("sessions.php", {"name": brandName}, function(results) {
        $('#SOME-ELEMENT').html(results);
    });
}
```

How I'm getting my title();:

```
<?php
    // Set session variables
    $_SESSION["item"][] = get_the_title();
?>
```

Is this some thing I can use? And could someone help me with the code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What the error you got ?

Comment: Change the URL `example.com/reload.php` to `/reload.php`. If both the pages at the same domain and same folder.

Comment: Keep in mind that a session set in a remote page will not be available in the local page until you reload. You can echo the AJAX response, but that does not set the session locally.

Comment: It doesn't show an error. It just won't echo the title. My AJAX script works like this. Does it matter if the .php page and the titles are not in the same folder. Because its a wordpress installation.

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: Yes, Yes, No and Yes. It only shows that the files are linked correct. It does update the div I want. But just not with the title. @JayBlanchard

Comment: What Is The Issue @Steggie ?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to echo get_the_title(); using the AJAX script we worked on in my other question. So that it will echo the_title of the items in the `div .txtHint` But I don't know why I can echo the title in my HTML but not using the AJAX script. @Nana Partykar. But it has to be in an array I guess because there are more than 10 items that need to be saved and remembered individually. So if I click on Item 1, 2, 6 and 7 these should be echoed in `.txtHint`.

Comment: Yeahhh... I know its alot.

Comment: No, Its not tough though. I need to study your page actions first.

Comment: If you need files or something like that. Please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure on what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but here's a quick and dirty example of making an HTTP request (POST) with a name of a product, storing it in a PHP session, and outputting all product names in the session:

HTML

```
<p>Product A <button class="add-product" data-product="Product A">Add Product</button></p>
<p>Product B <button class="add-product" data-product="Product B">Add Product</button></p>
<p>Product C <button class="add-product" data-product="Product C">Add Product</button></p>

<div id="response">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('.add-product').click(function() {
    var productName = $(this).data('product');

    $.post('addProduct.php', {productName: productName}, function(data) {
        $('#response').html(data);
    })
});
```

PHP (addProduct.php)

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!array_key_exists('products', $_SESSION) || !is_array($_SESSION['products'])) {
    $_SESSION['products'] = [];
}

$productName = array_key_exists('productName', $_POST) ? (string) $_POST['productName'] : '';

if ($productName) {
    $_SESSION['products'][] = $productName;
}
?>
<h4>Your added products:</h4>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $product): ?>
    <li><?php echo htmlspecialchars($product); ?></li>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Show how would that be in my AJAX script?

`$(".ajaxform").submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "example.com/reload.php",
      success: function(data) {
        $(".txtHint").html(data);    
       },
     error: function() {
        alert('Not OKay');
        }
    });
      return false;
 });`

Comment: Oh and that peace of code is something I found on Stackoverflow. Im not using it. I was just wondering if I could use it in my script. And then how? @Frank T

Comment: Your code almost works Frank T thanks! One thing it posts the title more then one (four times to be exact)... @Frank T It posts the 1st 4 time, the second 3 times, the 3rd 2 times and the last one 1 time. Is there a count some where?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I fully understand what you mean. Could you please update your original question with the latest code example?

Comment: Sorry @Frank T i solved the problem! Thanks for the code!